# Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'Job'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I trying to load data in to a table view and I have errors - Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'Job' & Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'DateTime'.  Job & DateTime are my variables that I want to display in my tableview cell.  How do I get rid of the error?

```
// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
extension CalendarViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return displayName.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        cell.Job.text = displayName[indexPath.row]
        cell.DateTime.text = displayDateTime[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to cast the cell to the proper type.

Answer (score 1):

As Job and DateTime are not default members of 
UITableviewCell class you need to typecast UITableViewCell to your custom tableviewcell class as shown,

```
// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
extension CalendarViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! YourTableCellClass

        cell.Job.text = displayName[indexPath.row]
        cell.DateTime.text = displayDateTime[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your `Job` and `DateTime` is not a property of Apple's `UITableViewCell`. What you have to do is to cast your cell to `YourTableCell` like

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! YourTableCell
```

Besides, your property name is not ideal. It should start with lower case. Only Class and other type name should start with upper case. So please change to `job` and `dateTime`.

The full naming is just like what @rmaddy said:

> Class, struct, and enum names start with uppercase. Variable, function, and case names start with lowercase.

Comment: Class, struct, and enum names start with uppercase. Variable, function, and case names start with lowercase.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for adding those :)

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.